# How to compare an input value with database value in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model called CustomizedBooking where I need to validate paid amount value equal to the price column of the database.
Following is code snippet

```
validate :paid_amount_and_price
def paid_amount_and_price_check
    if paid_amount == price column value of the database
    errors.add(:paid_amount, "Must be equal to the price to process further!")
end
```

Please! somebody, suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code in model:

```
validate :paid_amount_and_price
def paid_amount_and_price_check
    unless paid_amount.to_f == price.to_f
      errors.add(:paid_amount, "Must be equal to the price to process further!")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to use any custom validation here, try this:

```
validates_numericality_of :paid_amount,
                          equal_to: ->(object) { object.price.to_f },
                          message: "Must be equal to the price to process further!"
```

or

```
validates :paid_amount, 
          :numericality => { equal_to: ->(object) { object.price.to_f },
                             message: "Must be equal to the price to process further!" }
```